# Can Spring-SAML and Basic auth work together for the same URL pattern?

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml

I have requirement for our application where we need to implement Spring SAML within our app to enable SSO for one customer. However we need to maintain existing login flow using spring-security for other customer.Basically we have  a  mobility application thats talking to the enterprise application , and currently we use basic authentication.  And now we are trying to add support for SAML, I was wondering they can both work together, question is: 
1)I want to enable SAML based on some registry 
2)Otherwise I want my app to behave normally (i.e basic auth)  Should they both configured in the same spring-security-context.xml?